# How to get height of widget in flutter using RenderBox?

Tags: flutter, dart

I've written the following function in which I pass GlobalKey that I assigned to a widget, and I'm storing the returned height in an array called 'heightsList'. But for some reason I'm getting a wrong height, which is 65( which is same for all widgets, I tried for dropdown, checkbox and radio).
However, I get the correct height(269 for checkbox and 77 for dropdown) when I perform a hot reload(ie, the function gets called again).

```
void getSizes(GlobalKey key, int index) async {
  if(key.currentContext!=null) {
    RenderBox renderBox = key.currentContext.findRenderObject();
    heightsList[index] = renderBox.size.height;
  }
}
```

Here is an example of the widget
(NOTE: CustomCheckBox is hardly any different from checkbox) -

```
Container(
   key: keys[index],
   child: CustomCheckBox(
       item: item,
       count: i,
       onChanged: (dynamic response) {
           responseDetails = response;
       },
       formItems: data['data']['FORM'][0]['sections']['sections'][index]['definition']
   )
)
```

I have no idea where that 65 is coming from. I'm just trying to get proper height of the widget. So if there is anything that I'm doing wrong, or there is any other way around, please let me know.

Any help is much appreciated.